# Retrieving structure from vector of structs following a find_if

Tags: c++

I have written this small program to search for a struct inside a vector of structs. After this line in the code below, how should I extract the element of the vector that matched. i.e. the structure and its contents.

```
        if (std::find_if(jobInfoVector.begin(), jobInfoVector.end(), pred) != jobInfoVector.end())
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "boost/bind.hpp"

using namespace std;
struct jobInfo
{
        std::string jobToken;
        time_t startTime;
        time_t endTime;
};
typedef struct jobInfo JobInfo;

int main()
{
        std::vector<JobInfo> jobInfoVector;
        JobInfo j1 = {"rec1",1234,3456};
        JobInfo j2 = {"rec2",1244,3656};
        JobInfo j3 = {"rec3",1254,8456};

        jobInfoVector.push_back(j1);
        jobInfoVector.push_back(j2);
        jobInfoVector.push_back(j3);

        auto pred = [](const JobInfo &jobinfo) { return jobinfo.startTime == 1234; };

        if (std::find_if(jobInfoVector.begin(), jobInfoVector.end(), pred) != jobInfoVector.end())
        {
                cout << "got a match" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "Did not get a match" << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: If i had iterated through a vector with an iterator, i can atleast do a *it.jobToken or a *it.startTime etc. In this case, not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the result of the `std::find_if()` as an iterator, then dereference to extract its components. Like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "boost/bind.hpp"

using namespace std;
struct jobInfo
{
        std::string jobToken;
        time_t startTime;
        time_t endTime;
};
typedef struct jobInfo JobInfo;

int main()
{
        std::vector<JobInfo> jobInfoVector;
        JobInfo j1 = {"rec1",1234,3456};
        JobInfo j2 = {"rec2",1244,3656};
        JobInfo j3 = {"rec3",1254,8456};

        jobInfoVector.push_back(j1);
        jobInfoVector.push_back(j2);
        jobInfoVector.push_back(j3);

        auto pred = [](const JobInfo &jobinfo) { return jobinfo.startTime == 1234; };
        auto it = std::find_if(jobInfoVector.begin(), jobInfoVector.end(), pred);
        if (it != jobInfoVector.end())
        {
                jobInfo& match = *it;
                cout << "got a match" << endl;
                //Do whatever job with match
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "Did not get a match" << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that i use C++11, so this answer suited me the best.

Answer (score 3):

You just need keep the iterator returned from [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), and use it later.

> Return value
> Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or
> last if no such element is found.

E.g. you can apply [If Statements with Initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#If_Statements_with_Initializer) (since C++17):

```
if (auto it = std::find_if(jobInfoVector.begin(), jobInfoVector.end(), pred); it != jobInfoVector.end())
{
        cout << "got a match" << endl;
        // use it from here...
}
else
{
        cout << "Did not get a match" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is it valid to include two lines of code inside `if()` phrase?

Comment: @K.R.Park It's allowed since C++17.

Comment: Oh great. that feature seems very useful. Thank you for letting me know. +1.